# Anonymous type isn't anonymous

Tags: c#

I have a class which has a string property:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can select a List of the `Name`s from a `List<User> MyListOfUsers` like so:

```
List<string> MyNames = MyListOfUsers.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

In my asbent-mindedness, I had first tried to do the same via an anonymous type:

```
List<string> MyNames = MyListOfUsers.Select(x => new { x.Name }).ToList();
```

But that tells me

> Cannot convert type `List< <anonymous type: string Name> > to List<string>`

But it knows it's a string? Why didn't it allow this syntax when it clearly knows the 'anonymous type' is a string?

Comment: `new { }` is an anonymous type object and `new { x.Name }` is an anonymous type object with a string property and `x.Name` is just a string object. So a string object and anonymous type with string a property are not the same.

Comment: Have a look at the class that gets generated for your anonymous type, tell me if it should be the same as a string https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWDkQHQBkBLAOwEdMYsBmZMRAYUQG9ZE3kbxEBVAZwFMATrBYx2HHEgByAQwC2/ZogDm/AC7pEAjYgC+rdiBok1iAPJqAFkIAKggPYAHIWoCeS1Tu2b9MX+KNkVEQAWQAKAEpmA3E2GNiANxlBRBleABNEAF5EYn4Ad0QiXjUAHj4hAD5Iilj2ePEklMF+XgBXABs1XmzUjNwAZX4O/gBjNTCAD2zK3IKlSdxZBT0I3AAVe2KJiNr2X10gA

Comment: Ahhh of course @ChetanRanpariya yes that makes sense thank you, I would have realised if I'd created `new { x.Name, x.OtherProperty }` - and that's why there are two pointy brackets `< < > >`  Silly Me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I might just do that and with a comment for my future self to look back and laugh at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anonymous type you are creating is not a string. It's a class with a string property called Name.

Your code is equivalent to

```
List<string> MyNames = MyListOfUsers.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name }).ToList();
```

but C# allows you to infer a property name of an anonymous class from the source by saying `new {x.Name}` instead of `new {Name = x.Name}`.

Anonymous types in C# are classes that inherit from object and even if they only contain a single string property, they cannot cast to string as the [documentation explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and
> that cannot be cast to any type except object.

As to your initial intention, this is correct

```
List<string> MyNames = MyListOfUsers.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

The usage of a new anonymous class would not just be a different syntax but result in different memory footprint and GC load. It's unnecessary in your use case.

Comment: Yup, I've just realised if I'd created two properties in that anonymous type I would have seen this straight away, I think it's too late in the night for me.